# How to record video of webdriver test in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver, mocha.js, protractor

I am planning to use either of node.JS webdriver/Mocha/Protractor. Is there a easy way of recording the video in either of these?

I have looked at the option of recording the whole screen using ffmpeg when the test runs but if there is any nodejs library that would help me directly record the video of any of these. I would use that.